# In WinRT is it possible to ask for the current OS version?

Tags: windows-8

Using WinRT can I determine if the current OS is:

1. Windows RT
2. Windows 8 Core
3. Windows 8 Pro
4. Windows 8 Ent

**Is it possible?**

Note, the question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125324/get-os-version-in-winrt-metro-app-c-sharp) appears to be a duplicate but it is a pre-release question. Much of the API was changed throughout the releases. The answer to that question was that it was not possible. Is that still true? Surely not.

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125324/get-os-version-in-winrt-metro-app-c-sharp

Comment: No, that is a pre-release question! Are you ++sure++ it is still the same answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using the webview seems to be a reliable and pretty quick way to get the processor you are running on. To determine pro versus, enterprise. No. I can't find a way.

But if you are interested in how to determine the processor and go from there?
Check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16996176/265706

Answer (score 1):

If it can be done, it's not easy and it will have to be inferred from data you can get about the running system.  The docs are very unclear about this unfortunately.  For example, the [GetNativeSystemInfo function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/ms724340) is allowed under a Metro style app.  [See this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br205762).

However, the docs for GetNativeSystemInfo link to [an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/ms724429) on how to get the OS Version that uses several APIs that are **not** on the list for Metro style apps, but the example is still under the Metro docs.  It is also unclear what the [response from GetNativeSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/ms724958) will be on an ARM processor.

The bottom line is that this is a bad approach and bound to cause fragility in your code.  My advice is to avoid trying to do this.

Comment: I agree, still wanting to find out though - I bet there's a way

Answer (score 0):

You can get the OS version number with some risk that it might not be correct by using the devices API to get the driver version number for a low-level system component like the HAL.

http://attackpattern.com/2013/03/device-information-in-windows-8-store-apps/ has more information and sample code (disclosure, I wrote that post & code)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.packageid.architecture.aspx

```
var architecture = packageId.architecture;


var package = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current;
var packageId = package.id;
var version = packageId.version;

var output = [ "Name: \"" + packageId.name + "\"",
           "Version: " + version.major + "." + version.minor + "." 
                       + version.build + "." + version.revision,
           "Architecture: " + packageId.architecture,
           "ResourceId: \"" + packageId.resourceId + "\"",
           "Publisher: \"" + packageId.publisher + "\"",
           "PublisherId: \"" + packageId.publisherId + "\"",
           "FullName: \"" + packageId.fullName + "\"",
           "FamilyName: \"" + packageId.familyName + "\"",
           "IsFramework: " + package.isFramework ];
```

Comment: Doesn't that tell you about the current package, not the platform?

Comment: Yes its about the current package... mostly "Neutral" not ARM or something specific...