# How to detect in a program if the windows system is windows8 or windows8 rt

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I need to know whether the system is windows8 or windows8 rt,( arm or intel/amd architecthre).
Is there someone can help me ?

Comment: Is you are asking developer point of view or user point of view. just add some description about exactly what you want

Comment: Here is a way to determine the process architecture.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975386/could-i-know-if-my-app-is-running-on-windows-rt-with-c