# Getting the OS version from within a Windows Store App

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-store-apps

How can I retrieve the operating system's complete version string (e.g. 6.2.9200.0) from within a Windows Store application? The usual `Environment.OSVersion` API is not available there, so is there anything equivalent?

Comment: take a look at this thread (an argument against needing/doing this in the first place :)) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125324/get-os-version-in-winrt-metro-app-c-sharp

Comment: thanks Jim, but in my case the actual OS version IS relevant for statistics purposes - to determine the users distribution by OS version - i know what i'm doing, it's not helpful for me at all an answer like "trust me, you won't need it, you're doing it wrong" like that thread seems to imply