# Get OS version in Windows Store Apps

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am new to Windows 8 Store Apps, and have a requirement of getting OS version, but did not get any help or namespace.

```
System.Environment.OSVersion
```

is not available over here.

Can any one guide me on this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get OS-Version in WinRT Metro App C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125324/get-os-version-in-winrt-metro-app-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate. Check out the full thread for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125324/get-os-version-in-winrt-metro-app-c-sharp/15792337#15792337) though, because unless you're doing analytics on your user-base, you shouldn't need it.