# Get OS Version in windows universal 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I am developing an app that is Windows universal 8.1 app. I want to get os version. before Windows 10 Mobile i could suppose that version is 8.1 but currently this assumption this is not true. is there a way for get os version in a Windows 8.1 Universal app?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath i see that. but is there a way to find out that device is 8.1 or 10?

Comment: Of course, they run different .NET versions. If you build the app for 8.1 then it can run in 8.1 and 10; but if you build it for 10 it won't run in 8.1.   
Take into account that you cannot know if it's 8.1 or 10 if you build for 8.1

Comment: @cFrozenDeath it is very strange for me why Microsoft doesn't exposed such Api to developers. then how AdDuplex knows OS Version(i think they have sdk for windows universal)?

Comment: I think Microsoft wants you to check for for specific features and not to rely on OS version.

Comment: @ForguesR i need version because my app send version to server for statistical purpose

Comment: I have been looking over Google and MSDN, I couldn't find absolutely no API to check this. Do as @ForguesR says and decide the platform based on a W10-only feature.

Comment: You might consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15792337/1980659)  but it looks like a lot of work.

Comment: I would think any analytics framework you use in your app would get the os version for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight apps can use the .NET version APIs. There is no supported mechanism to get a version number in Universal 8.1 apps, but you can try using reflection to get the Windows 10 `AnalyticsInfo` class, which will at least tell you the version number if you are running on Windows 10.

**Note:** Checking the OS version is *almost always* the wrong thing to do, unless you're simply displaying it to the user (eg, in an "About" box) or sending it to your back-end analytics server for number crunching. It should not be used to make any run-time decisions, because in general it's a poor proxy for *whatever-you're-actually-trying-to-do*.

Here is a sample:

```
var analyticsInfoType = Type.GetType(
  "Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsInfo, Windows, ContentType=WindowsRuntime");
var versionInfoType = Type.GetType(
  "Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsVersionInfo, Windows, ContentType=WindowsRuntime");
if (analyticsInfoType == null || versionInfoType == null)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("Apparently you are not on Windows 10");
  return;
}

var versionInfoProperty = analyticsInfoType.GetRuntimeProperty("VersionInfo");
object versionInfo = versionInfoProperty.GetValue(null);
var versionProperty = versionInfoType.GetRuntimeProperty("DeviceFamilyVersion");
object familyVersion = versionProperty.GetValue(versionInfo);

long versionBytes;
if (!long.TryParse(familyVersion.ToString(), out versionBytes))
{
  Debug.WriteLine("Can't parse version number");
  return;
}

Version uapVersion = new Version((ushort)(versionBytes >> 48),
  (ushort)(versionBytes >> 32),
  (ushort)(versionBytes >> 16),
  (ushort)(versionBytes));

Debug.WriteLine("UAP Version is " + uapVersion);
```